# If API return me error, hide message

Tags: php

I use Google API for a customer to display a video playlist on his website. I just want to protect this if the customer has some trouble.

If the API key or the playlist ID is wrong, i have lots of PHP error where i call the API. I just want, if the API returns me an error show a message like "Something is wrong, come later" because actually my website explode. How can I make it ?

My code is like:

```
<?php foreach ($playlist->items AS $item): 
    echo $item->snippet->title;
endforeach; ?>
```

The JSON result when the API is wrong for example:

```
{
   "error": {
      "errors": [
         {
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "keyInvalid",
            "message": "Bad Request"
         }
       ],
       "code": 400,
       "message": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code and the JSON response when an argument is missing.

Comment: @AymDev I edit my post. Thx

Comment: U should read about Exception handling in PHP. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Comment: Is the `errors` empty when it runs correctly ?

Comment: how are you detecting the error condition and reading the error response? The PHP code you've shown only allows the possibility of a successful response. How are you calling the API and getting the response? You need to check the returned HTTP status code and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do something like this:

```
<?php if ($playlist && !empty($playlist->items)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($playlist->items AS $item): ?>
        <?php echo $item->snippet->title; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<p>Something is wrong, come later</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```